# Propagating error callbacks in Node.js, and avoiding all the extra cruft?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I'm writing an API in Node/Express. I need an endpoint that when you hit it, it performs three API calls to an external API and then stores the results in Mongo. Basically a database refresh.

I'm new to node, asynchronous programming, callbacks, etc. and all of it is making my head spin. This is what I have so far. My main concerns is with how I am handling errors. The only way I can see it working is doing something like below, passing a call back into each of my functions and then if there's an error present return that callback with the error parameter, and so on, until it bubbles back to the top where the express server can create the appropriate response. This all seems really ugly and really arbitrary, extra paramters in each function, and the flow doesn't make much sense, and I feel like there has to be a better way.

I know that there are promises, and I am open to a promise solution especially if it's the standard way of doing these things, but I would also like to know the way I should be doing this in classic javascript.

```
var app = require('express')();
var request = require('request');

app.put('/refresh', function(req, res) {
  updateDatabase(function (error) {
    if (error) {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      res.send(200);
    }
  });
});

function updateDatabase(callback) {
  var handleErrors = function (error) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }
  }
  id1 = 'uniqueId1';
  id2 = 'uniqueId2';
  id3 = 'uniqueId3';
  putLatestStuff(id1, handleErrors);
  putLatestStuff(id2, handleErrors);
  putLatestStuff(id3, handleErrors);
  callback();
} 

function putLatestStuff(id, callback) {
  request('http://api.com/stuff/' + id, putIntoMongo(error, response, body, callback));
  callback();

function putIntoMongo(error, response, body, callback) { // ??? all these parameters now required
  // obviously not correct code
  mongodriver.add(body, anotherFreakingCallback(callback));
}

function anotherFreakingCallback(error, result, callback) {
  if (error) {
    return callback(error);
  }
  callback();
}
```

This design is awful, and I'm sure I'm doing it incorrectly.

Comment: have you considered promises?

Comment: @akaphenom From my OP: "I know that there are promises, and I am open to a promise solution especially if it's the standard way of doing these things, but I would also like to know the way I should be doing this in classic javascript."

Comment: promises will be the standard way.

Comment: Start here: https://www.promisejs.org/ if you attempt to do something and have questions re-post with your attempt to use promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per everyone's advice, promises ended up being the way to fix this.

```
var app = require('express')();
var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');

app.put('/refresh', function(req, res) {
  var ids = ['uniqueId1', 'uniqueId2', 'uniqueId3'];
  updateDatabase(ids)
    .then(function (result) {
      res.status(200).send(result);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      res.status(500).send({error: error});
    });
});

function updateDatabase(uniqueIds) {
  var promises = [];
  uniqueIds.forEach(function (id) {
    promises.push(putLatestStuff(id));
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
} 

function putLatestStuff(id) {
  return getLatestData(id)
    .then(putIntoDatabase);
}

function getLatestData(id) {
  return fetch('http://api.com/stuff/' + id);
}

function putIntoDatabase(data) {
  return mongo.put(data); // mongo.put is fake function that returns a promise
}
```

Comment: Although there is nothign wrong with the above approach, there is a q-io module which handles HTTP in promise form, instead of writing your own defer/reject/resolve code.  FWIW, anyhow